# Classpath entry org.maven.ide.eclipse.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER will not be exported or published.

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven, m2eclipse

sometimes when importing a maven project in eclipse, i get the following error:

```
Classpath entry org.maven.ide.eclipse.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER will not be exported or published. Runtime ClassNotFoundExceptions may result.
```

although the classpath file on the svn repo contains the maven dependencies entry:

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.maven.ide.eclipse.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
```

i know the workaround to solve the issue by going to project deployment assembly and adding maven dependencies manually (which will add the entry above again !), but i am curious to know, why such error is generated, although classpath contains the dependencies entry ?

please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's called Loose classpath:
Loose classpath support is an optional mechanism that allows for the inclusion of Eclipse Java development Tools classpath artifacts in a dynamic Web project's WEB-INF/lib folder.
You can add dependencies using the Java EE Module Dependencies page, but you can also add the Web libraries from the Libraries page under the Java Build Page.
You can include Jars, external Jars, libraries, and variables.
The project validator now detects loose classpath issues and reports them in the problems view.

Additional info:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.javaee.doc/topics/tlooseclasspath.html